# Unable to start weblogic server

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am getting an error while starting a Weblogic server.

```
ORA-28000:the account is locked
ORA-01017:invalid username/password;logon denied.
```

Initially I received an `ORA-28001` error.

Steps that I tried:

- change Database system password.
- reset passwords in JDBC folder XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Your account is locked. Simplest is to change the password and unlock the account again.

```
alter user USERNAME identified by "SecretP@ssword" account unlock;
```

But you'll need DBA privileges to do so on the database.

*ps. You need to change the password for the `USERNAME` you are trying to connect with. Not the `system` password. If you are indeed using `system` as your user, you will run into issues later.*